# Is it possible to run a loop when a new file is created in a folder?

Tags: java

So I have to make a program in java that automatically runs in the background and looks for a new .dat file and when it sees the new .dat file it then runs a .bat file to load data into a database. So far I have a program that watches for new file creation, modification, and deletion. I also have a script that runs the .bat file and loads the data into the database now i just need to connect the two but I am not sure how to go about this, If someone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Below is the code I have so far.

```
import static java.nio.file.LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent.Kind;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;


public class Order_Processing {

    public static void watchDirectoryPath(Path path)
    {
        try {
            Boolean isFolder = (Boolean) Files.getAttribute(path,
                    "basic:isDirectory", NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
            if (!isFolder)
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Path: " + path
                        + " is not a folder");
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Watching path: "+ path);
        FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem();
        try (WatchService service = fs.newWatchService())
        {
            path.register(service, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_MODIFY, ENTRY_DELETE);
            WatchKey key = null;
            while (true) 
            {
                key = service.take();

                Kind<?> kind = null;
                for (WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : key.pollEvents())
                {
                    kind = watchEvent.kind();
                    if (OVERFLOW == kind)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (ENTRY_CREATE == kind)
                    {
                        Path newPath = ((WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent)
                                .context();
                        System.out.println("New Path Created: " + newPath);
                    }
                    else if (ENTRY_MODIFY == kind)
                    {
                        Path newPath = ((WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent)
                                .context();
                        System.out.println("New path modified: "+ newPath);
                    }
                    else if (ENTRY_DELETE == kind)
                    {
                        Path newPath = ((WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent)
                                .context();
                        System.out.println("New path deleted: "+ newPath);
                    }
                }
                if (!key.reset())
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException ie)
        {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
                            throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File dir = new File("C:\\Paradigm");
    watchDirectoryPath(dir.toPath());

    //below is the script that runs the .bat file and it works if by itself
    //with out all the other watch code.
    try {
        String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", "C:\\Try.bat"};
        Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);           
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    }
 }
```

Comment: So you need to know how to run the .bat file and pass it some arguments?

Comment: Why not call the batch file in the event, instead of after you return from the watchDirectoryPath returns? Wouldn't this only run once? Is that all you need it to do? I'm trying to figure out exactly what you are asking. Can you describe more about what "connect the two" means in your context?

Comment: Just place the code that runs the `.BAT` file right where you print out that a new file has been detected.

Comment: What I meant was the code to run the bat file runs fine with out any of that file watching code. I was just trying to say that it works. Its suppose to run continuously in the background once i run the program.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because you have a `while (true)`. This makes sense because you are listening and want the to happen continuously; however, the bat call will never be executed because `watchDirectory(...)` will never terminate. To solve this, pull the rest of the main out into its own function like so

```
public static void executeBat() {
    try {
        String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", "C:\\Try.bat"};
        Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        // You should do something with this. 
        // DON'T JUST IGNORE FAILURES
    }
```

so that upon file creation, you can call that bat script

```
...
else if (ENTRY_CREATE == kind)
{
    Path newPath = ((WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent).context();
    executeBat();
}
...
```